# Select ARMA lag orders from ACF and PACF graphs

Tags: time-series, model-selection, autocorrelation, arma

I am new and self-starter with the time series. How should I set my ARMA parameters with these ACF/PACF charts?[image]

**EDIT:**
The actual data below:

```
2016-01-02,39.75951351903896
2016-01-03,44.19802892451088
2016-01-04,35.887366090361105
2016-01-05,47.52400693730769
2016-01-06,31.983702722150007
2016-01-07,18.057180708258063
2016-01-08,22.655207573981325
2016-01-13,24.032670139522725
2016-01-14,36.12322561430137
2016-01-15,20.187763237565214
2016-01-16,48.855922908363624
2016-01-17,48.39927291059999
2016-01-18,56.44049644907896
2016-01-19,37.69458044227272
2016-01-20,-70.50059842571429
2016-01-21,26.9161037942807
2016-01-22,43.75994638408695
2016-01-23,48.373229398888896
2016-01-24,12.572153745333333
2016-01-25,48.89474204682609
2016-01-26,28.538047387723083
2016-01-27,34.30517480442857
2016-01-28,47.78075214078947
2016-01-29,-78.68819873655555
2016-01-30,-28.97592228
2016-01-31,-7.046974465
2016-02-02,37.29205861404628
2016-02-03,42.25382787887097
2016-02-04,65.94607071840626
2016-02-05,12.651954309425003
2016-02-06,46.63573759473846
2016-02-07,32.25278198860416
2016-02-08,34.77058575470422
2016-02-14,-25.36701266
2016-02-15,-60.79984227216667
2016-02-16,56.02435255765384
2016-02-17,28.746407145797463
2016-02-18,16.550378951229508
2016-02-19,15.82792759401235
2016-02-20,4.990341175500004
2016-02-21,70.1803637223889
2016-02-22,31.350118170803576
2016-02-23,-86.2847876852143
2016-02-24,23.342789667022725
2016-02-25,39.77064584494442
2016-02-26,51.5940791500274
2016-02-27,51.88317634523076
2016-02-28,37.16568923229413
2016-02-29,-47.748961607533325
2016-03-02,21.166933922139705
2016-03-03,33.240946892873026
2016-03-04,46.14479273363332
2016-03-05,47.681106868636384
2016-03-06,34.2138656794186
2016-03-07,59.61628564819644
2016-03-08,50.47316287450001
2016-03-13,-65.29583746075001
2016-03-14,-34.110463839375
2016-03-15,49.83565921616666
2016-03-16,51.81790938512626
2016-03-17,32.48205597794505
2016-03-18,15.126982130323526
2016-03-19,-145.59020894999998
2016-03-20,-82.70413420999999
2016-03-21,30.991773486115378
2016-03-22,25.136369381434783
2016-03-23,9.599847528214283
2016-03-24,27.69982853081708
2016-03-25,-51.212730021000006
2016-03-26,-32.23208046
2016-03-28,-64.1687965
2016-03-29,45.859266805243244
2016-03-30,24.186714096475733
2016-03-31,34.76727254327955
2016-04-01,38.16134432345833
2016-04-02,35.63535579801471
2016-04-03,43.65374674151612
2016-04-04,17.67314425440425
2016-04-05,26.915555915125
2016-04-06,20.538772073199997
2016-04-07,20.102776686333335
2016-04-08,21.979722049833327
2016-04-13,45.928575165329676
2016-04-14,-32.48944289471428
2016-04-15,17.491105200894744
2016-04-16,64.69551535751515
2016-04-17,28.516430059499996
2016-04-18,40.95893484309175
2016-04-19,28.020746872985303
2016-04-20,30.130044503729412
2016-04-21,-58.18807158536842
2016-04-22,-25.337561036916664
2016-04-23,-26.627664854
2016-04-24,-28.69160864
2016-04-25,39.08488299530122
2016-04-26,46.435291118965225
2016-04-27,23.887642614118107
2016-04-28,-26.948563170055554
2016-04-29,19.046125541384615
2016-04-30,16.587165837604164
2016-05-01,13.155560922764712
2016-05-02,49.09833023170666
2016-05-03,40.75153917545162
2016-05-04,-11.1458260315
2016-05-05,20.513396592663636
2016-05-06,28.887168281440005
2016-05-07,37.936864492225
2016-05-08,33.74335998025926
2016-05-13,29.86262297474258
2016-05-14,38.24630225486047
2016-05-15,-40.245916527000006
2016-05-16,-41.557438196375
2016-05-17,24.794384094421687
2016-05-18,44.023555185375024
2016-05-19,5.268354276342105
2016-05-20,-40.386544623
2016-05-21,-72.32440148666667
2016-05-22,-65.92112163
2016-05-23,28.8193746211875
2016-05-24,50.234793735896915
2016-05-25,30.19691055108275
2016-05-26,19.686875528722226
2016-05-27,27.886102861170215
2016-05-28,15.590281383125
2016-05-29,39.651467377961545
2016-05-30,6.090026817734378
2016-05-31,25.362722162576084
2016-06-01,24.68601314195161
2016-06-02,36.179651624999984
2016-06-03,-26.168601790571433
2016-06-04,2.0638147895312495
2016-06-05,15.869253558152543
2016-06-06,30.97266805041892
2016-06-07,18.786122524463412
2016-06-08,62.50297165851221
2016-06-13,12.582850628634413
2016-06-14,17.844550084799994
2016-06-15,34.29525451988392
2016-06-16,19.03949167980612
2016-06-17,38.18312853862858
2016-06-18,-53.854408188923074
2016-06-19,-46.784044466875
2016-06-20,-29.811334852448272
2016-06-21,26.963462620788896
2016-06-22,33.756293176753616
2016-06-23,39.73173145911925
2016-06-24,50.64357838118183
2016-06-25,48.389665883354155
2016-06-26,9.094675531958334
2016-06-27,33.42214236674038
2016-06-28,25.31476515070093
2016-06-29,46.719154985418385
2016-06-30,30.091621642547025
2016-07-01,12.536105745310346
2016-07-02,42.674479050833334
2016-07-03,-13.53104158542857
2016-07-04,33.34080500357694
2016-07-06,33.21655168859616
2016-07-07,-87.41816937799999
2016-07-08,40.30393382614999
2016-07-13,34.82197758462265
2016-07-14,17.943902780436776
2016-07-15,25.110484135747257
2016-07-16,25.47542131667347
2016-07-17,26.70378401413636
2016-07-18,36.55949755945263
2016-07-19,21.239591675470592
2016-07-20,30.53004775844682
2016-07-21,38.65555894068421
2016-07-22,38.498780407582295
2016-07-23,64.67681735688889
2016-07-24,11.738560087312504
2016-07-25,-128.0038304
2016-07-26,37.739667621432446
2016-07-27,34.701622793094025
2016-07-28,-1.7783829946923093
2016-07-29,25.485521557819443
2016-07-30,50.257818642923084
2016-07-31,58.34552953883872
2016-08-01,31.165026671109075
2016-08-02,-22.0858203566111
2016-08-03,43.489689993647076
2016-08-04,31.459597491236853
2016-08-05,-5.974649260750001
2016-08-06,30.16309143433028
2016-08-07,25.860340325521754
2016-08-08,18.845143551831327
2016-08-13,27.317894660815796
2016-08-14,17.68989662983334
2016-08-15,33.30597511965824
2016-08-16,25.27378402822224
2016-08-17,19.28480775032501
2016-08-18,36.93733733110236
2016-08-19,39.781529773118805
2016-08-20,31.724542664115386
2016-08-21,60.21249229103573
2016-08-22,39.52576312805881
2016-08-23,27.766367975900902
2016-08-24,40.61433045760999
2016-08-25,48.67369527632799
2016-08-26,18.439678647561973
2016-08-27,30.46624090141937
2016-08-28,4.071043576733334
2016-08-29,24.64217842261111
2016-08-30,23.941792209643562
2016-08-31,19.871698113300756
```

Comment: Is that perhaps a homework exercise? If so, add the [tag:self-study] and read its [Wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you think about your problem so far, and we will help you advance.

Comment: It is a training exercise.. I have no lags out of boundaries.. so from my point of view there is no autocorrelation in this TS. Is that correct?

Comment: So far so good.

Comment: It's a time series on a daily purchase. I should obtain a out-of-sample forecast 14 days into future. Starting from those graphs I was thinking to use a ARMA(19,18)... But I think I am completely wrong..

Comment: So when there is virtually no autocorrelation and no partial autocorrelation, what ARMA orders do textbooks normally suggest?

Comment: It should be a white noise?

Comment: Yes, which means ARMA(p,q) with p=? and q=?

Comment: probably 1 and 1?

Comment: From my point of view I can't predict anything without autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation. So in this case I should stop or use an ARMA(0,0).. which doesn't do anything...

Comment: Why (1,1) if there is no (partial-) autocorrelation? ARMA(0,0) is the correct answer. And if the selection of ARMA(0,0) surprises you in general -- sometimes indeed it is better to "do nothing" rather than "do something" and end up with an inferior result.

Comment: Do you have actual data and if so please post it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have daily data . A cardinal rule when trying to form an ARIMA model is that you need equally spaced observations and no missing values . If the # of missing values are few then one can always fill in a zero and a replacement value can often be suggested (pulse anomaly). You have a number of missing days so all bets are off . Please fill in the missing days as best as you can as you might have day-to-day auto-correlation and potentially deterministic structure due to particular days-of-the-week etc . Please re-post your complete time series and your corrected acf and pacf.